# Cron error: running commands is over the maximum limit

Tags: linux, cron

I have a cronjob on my web server, which executes the PHP script on regular basis.

Everything had been running fine so far, but then the cronjob stopped working all of a sudden. And every time the cron is supposed to execute, I receive this strange error report in my e-mail:

```
=== Information ===
Result[7422]: ERROR
Error Reason: Aborting! Running Commands (1) is Over the Maximum Limit (1).
Duration Time: 00d 00h 00m 00s
Duration Period: 2021-04-28 08:00:01 - 2021-04-28 08:00:01
```

Does anybody have an idea of what might cause this weird error and how to get rid of it?

Comment: The error implies that the last invocation of this command is still running.  Have you checked `ps -axf` to see if that's true?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Turns out it was indeed running and I called the `kill` command to stop it. In a few hours it should be clear whether cron shall execute properly or not.